One CheckboxList with data from multiple columns
I need a checkboxlist that will display data from two fields. For example. Product A is available in style 1 or 2, Product B is available in style 2 or 3, Product C is available in style 4. The checkboxlist should contain 1, 2, 3 and 4 in ascending order.
<asp:CheckBoxList 
    ID="CheckBoxListStyle" 
    Cssclass="CBL" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceId="SqlStyle"         
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxListStyle_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataTextField="style1" 
    DataValueField="style2">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlStyle" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DC %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT style1, style2 FROM products ORDER BY ASC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

I was able to do sequential checkboxlists and style them to make it look like one list, but then the styles aren't in ascending order as a whole.

To achieve your goal of displaying a combined list of distinct styles from both style1 and style2 in a single CheckBoxList, sorted in ascending order, you can use the following approach:
Modify the SQL Query: Use a UNION to combine the two fields into a single column, which will remove duplicates.
Bind the Result Programmatically: Fetch the combined list from the SQL query and bind it to the CheckBoxList in the code-behind.
<asp:CheckBoxList 
   ID="CheckBoxListStyle" 
   CssClass="CBL" 
   runat="server" 
   AutoPostBack="True"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxListStyle_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
    
<asp:SqlDataSource 
   ID="SqlStyle" 
   runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DC %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT style1 FROM products 
      UNION 
         SELECT DISTINCT style2 FROM products 
         ORDER BY style1 ASC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

Code-Behind (C#):
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Create a list to hold all styles
        List<string> styles = new List<string>();

        // Execute the SqlDataSource to retrieve data
        DataView dataView = (DataView)SqlStyle.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach (DataRowView row in dataView)
        {
            // Add styles from both columns to the list
            string style1 = row["style1"].ToString();
            string style2 = row["style2"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(style1))
                styles.Add(style1);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(style2))
                styles.Add(style2);
        }

        // Remove duplicates and sort the list
        var distinctStyles = styles.Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).ToList();

        // Bind the sorted list to the CheckBoxList
        CheckBoxListStyle.DataSource = distinctStyles;
        CheckBoxListStyle.DataBind();
    }
}

How this work?
The UNION SQL query combines the values of style1 and style2 while eliminating duplicates.
In the code-behind, the data is fetched into a List, which is then deduplicated using Distinct() and sorted using OrderBy().
The sorted list is bound to the CheckBoxList, ensuring all values are unique and sorted in ascending order.
This approach allows you to display a merged and sorted list of styles from both fields in a single CheckBoxList.
Regards!

Thank you so much for the quick response. I'm getting an error that "style2 is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table DefaultView."

When I change the SELECT statement in the Query Builder, it changes to "SELECT DISTINCT style2 FROM products AS products_1"

This error seems to be more related to the design of your database or the names of the columns. I based it on a table design with 3 string columns. I will try to found the error.

I verified that it was spelled correctly (even copied it from the table itself), but it still doesn't like "style2". I'm not sure if it matters, but there are 28 total columns in that table.

Why is the error saying "for table DefaultView" instead of "products'?  Should/(can) I explicitly point to table "products" in the code behind?
